# Axios - Calling secondary URL when primary fails

Tags: node.js, axios

Is there any ways to configure secondary url to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ?. When primary url fails, it must call the secondary url.

Comment: I developed the [_axios-middleware_](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/) module and there's [an example](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/examples/promise) that is similar, where on a auth error, it tries to log in, then retries the original call. You could use that to acheive what you want.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks a lot!! I will try it

Answer (score 5):

You could just call the second in the catch of the first:

```
      axios
      .get('url')
      .then(response => {
        // handle response
      })
      .catch(error => {
        axios
        .get('url2')
        .then(response => {
          // handle response
        });
      });
```

Comment: Any feature from `axios`? or we should do it manually like your answer?

Comment: As far as i know and can find, there is no chaining calls.. so my gues is the awnser i gave you..